# Shiny app that transfer files

Tags: shiny

I am trying to make a very simple app that transfers a user selected file to a fixed location. Then prints the results of the transfer (True / False). The syntax for copying is working outside of shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fileInput('file1', 'Choose 1st File',
            accept=c('text/csv', 
                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                     '.fastq' , '.fasta')) ,

  renderText('result')
)

server <- function(input , output){

  output$result <- renderPrint({

    file.copy(from = input$file1$datapath, 
              to = 'H:/Shiny/FileTransfer/TestLocation', 
              recursive = FALSE,
              copy.mode = TRUE)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: What exactly your problem/question is?

Comment: My question is that the app is not transferring the file. Hopefully someone knows why

Comment: Look at the answer below, I think is solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code. 1) The `renderPrint` function is never executed, use `verbatimTextOutput` instead. 2) The file name in `$datapath` is different from the original file, you should indicate the original name that is in `$name`, otherwise the destination file will have a name like `0` or some random number.

Below is your code modified with some extra information that could be useful for you. The function `file.path` is used to indicate the destination directory in addition with the original file name.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose 1st File',
            accept=c('text/csv', 
                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                     '.fastq' , '.fasta')) ,
  verbatimTextOutput('result')
)

server <- function(input , output){
  destDir <- 'H:/Shiny/FileTransfer/TestLocation'  
  output$result <- renderPrint({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      cat("NOT FILE\n")
      return(FALSE)
    }
    cat("Reading file:", inFile$name, "\n")
    cat("size:", inFile$size, " Bytes, type:", inFile$type, "\n")
    if (dir.exists(destDir)){
      cat("Copying file to:", destDir,"\n")
      result <- file.copy( inFile$datapath,
                           file.path(destDir, inFile$name) )
    } else {
      result <- FALSE
    }
    result
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: Geovany: Thank you! This is above and beyond

Comment: Glad it's useful for you.